# Lambda + API Gateway /**/* route?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to have a wildcard route defined and have the uri passed to the lambda for processing?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a proxy resource in API Gateway with a greedy path variable `{proxy+}` in resource path. The event object in the lambda used for integration should get the actual `path` which you can then process.

This blog post [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/) describes how to do it.